# IIS Express Site Name Change Results in Site Can't Be Reached

Tags: .net, visual-studio, iis-express

I have a web project in VS 2015. When I have the site URL as https://search.localhost.com in the project properties as so:

[image]

And the applicationhosts.config file has the entry:

```
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44302:search.localhost.com" />
```

Everything works fine like this.

I need to change the URL to https://service.localhost.com. So I change the properties to:

[image]

and in the applicationhosts.config file I change the entry to:

```
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44302:service.localhost.com" />
```

When I launch the site through IIS Express it now gives the error "This site can’t be reached".

Any idea what I'm missing in changing the site name?

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you configure the DNS records? If `service.localhost.com` does not go to your local machine, any error is expected.

Comment: Oh right, the Hosts file on my PC. Forgot about that. I added it and it worked. Thanks Lex Li

Comment: No. Forwarding requests on `service.localhost.com` to IIS Express is your responsibility (either set up a real DNS server and modify the records, or modify `hosts` file on your machine to emulate). Visual Studio and IIS Express won't do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was that I needed to modify my hosts file for the new URL to point to 127.0.0.1. Thanks Lex Li